# Oracle SQL Developer - How to add folders to frequently used locations in Open Folder interface

Tags: windows, file-shortcut, sqldeveloper

How do you add folders on the left side of the Open Folder interface? In one of my previous versions of the installation I had a couple different folders I frequently used in that part of the interface. Now I can't figure out how I got them there.

Using the standard Windows Folder icon to open a file (or File -> Open, or Ctrl-O). The window that pops up has on the left side "Home", "Desktop", and "Documents" as shortcuts to click on. There's space for more shortcuts and in a previous installation I actually had two more shortcuts to locations I used frequently. How do you add folders to that shortcut list?

Comment: I have the opposite question: I want to _remove_ a directory from the list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that if you open a certain folder often enough that it will add a shortcut to that location above the "Home", "Desktop", and "Documents" icons.

I still don't know if there's an option somewhere to manually add frequently opened locations to the File Open (Ctrl-O) dialogue window or what if you wanted to edit which shortcuts you have available there in a case where maybe you have multiple folders you open files from often. Sounds like a quality of life improvement opportunity for the developers of the software.

Comment: Any ideas how it works almost 2 years later? I cant figure it out either

Comment: I found (this)[http://www.winfaq.de/faq_html/Content/tip1000/onlinefaq.php?h=tip1415.htm], but that's really ugly.

Answer (score 4):

If your version is 3.2.20.09 then you can set it up at 
Tools > Preferences > Database > Worksheet > Select default path to look for scripts

Comment: Brilliant. Still works in Version 19.2.0.206.

Answer (score 0):

Do you refer to View > Files, or something completely else? Be more specific, please. I have SQLd opened right now (like any other day) and quickly run through a few less used options but can't figure out what you mean.

Comment: Using the standard Windows Folder icon to open a file. The window that pops up has on the left side "Home", "Desktop", and "Documents" as shortcuts to click on. There's space for more shortcuts and in a previous installation I actually had two more shortcuts to locations I used frequently. How do you add folders to that shortcut list?

Comment: I see. This is so called PlacesBar, on file dialog. Unfortunately, Java applications like SQLDeveloper use their own definition for places, so general rules for PlacesBar as Windows understand it doesn't apply here. I don't even know, if Java version is somehow easily editable but the question is related more to Java, than SQLdeveloper itself. Try to google for something like `java placesbar`, but brief try didn't reveal anything relevant.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I do appreciate it. The question is not about Java, it's about the design and use of the Oracle SQL Developer application itself. When I have a problem with a feature or the User Interface of MS Excel I don't go to a C++ forum (or whatever language/tool MS Excel is created from) for an answer. Maybe I posted this question in the wrong place?

Comment: I understand but I am not aware that SQL Developer supports editing placesbar, thus you're actually hacking the app, in which case you shouldn't be surprised there's no ready-to-serve answer. Anyway, try to ask in Oracle SQL Developer community, I'm pretty sure someone asked that question before. https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/sql_developer

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows and want to add or remove those folders that show in the PlacesBar, try this...Go to "%appdata%\SQL Developer". In that folder you will see one or more folders that start with "system" and have the versio number. Each one is from an installation or update of SQL Developer. Find the one you are using (biggest version number??) and search for two files (preferences.xml and product-preferences.xml).

Inside these files were lots of relative paths to the files I've opened. I just deleted a bunch that were in folders I didn't want to see anymore. That was good enough to clean up my PlacesBar. I'm not sure which deletes did the trick. Maybe someone else (or google search) can give an explanation of the sections found in those files.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP wants to add folders not remove them.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I am using SQL Developer 21.4.3 and in View tab you can actually open the location where your sql files are stored by Selecting "Files" option. For me on my mac, I store all my .sql files in ~/worksapce/sql-projects/sql-demo. I can navigate there and just double-click on any sql file I want to execute.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQEXs.png)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1115671)